# How to redirect the IP address of my server to the domain name?

Tags: nginx, ip, virtualhost, drupal-8, ubuntu-18.04

I migrated my Drupal 8 site from an Apache server to a Nginx server. The domain name displayed the site but the IP address does not redirect to the domain name.

How to do this ?

Do I have to leave this IP address or put my IP address ?

I tested this block and it shows errors :

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
server_name domaine.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.domaine.com$request_uri;
root /var/www/www-domaine-com/web;
```

sudo nginx -t

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domaine.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domaine.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to roll back your changes to a working solution, because your current configuration looks like it breaks your site completely. The following lines appear to be spurious and **need to be deleted**, at the top of the first `server` block:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
return 301 $scheme://www.s1biose.com$request_uri;
```

Your site is accessed using `https` which cannot be contacted by IP address, without most browsers complaining about an invalid certificate.

However, you can easily arrange for all `http` connections to be redirected to your site, by changing the one line `return 404; # managed by Certbot` to `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;`

The above assumes that there are no other `server` blocks in your configuration. You can use `nginx -T` (uppercase "T") to print the entire configuration as Nginx sees it, across all of its included files.